# Use Active Directory as authentication provider for CAS

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, cas

I'm currently configuring [CAS (formerly Jasig CAS)](https://apereo.github.io/cas), and want to make CAS use Active Directory as its LDAP backend. I'm having trouble understanding the documentation, and most guides are based on CAS 3.x, but I'm configuring CAS 5.1.x. Could someone give me an example for AD configuration in CAS?

Answer (score 0):

I found information on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apereo/cas/issues/2525).
The configuration from there is as follows:

```
cas.authn.ldap[0].type=AD
cas.authn.ldap[0].ldapUrl=ldap://192.168.0.2:3268
cas.authn.ldap[0].useSsl=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].useStartTls=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].connectTimeout=5000
cas.authn.ldap[0].baseDn=OU=My organisation,DC=myorg,DC=ee
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindDn=MYORG\\myuser
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindCredential=mypassword
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeId=sAMAccountName
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributePassword=unicodePwd
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeList=sAMAccountName,sn,cn
cas.authn.ldap[0].userFilter=(sAMAccountName={user})
cas.authn.ldap[0].dnFormat=%s@mycompany.com
cas.authn.ldap[0].allowMultiplePrincipalAttributeValues=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].subtreeSearch=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].usePasswordPolicy=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].failFast=false
```

Comment: Does it work for you? If yes, then please accept your own answer. If not, then you can make the necessary edit in your question itself!

Comment: It says I have to wait two days to accept my own answer.